# Split/extract values from record-type single column, apply user-defined function to multiple-row CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

Using PostgreSQL 9.2, I defined a function that takes one argument and returns a multi-column table.  I want to apply that function to multiple arguments that are in the rows of a CTE.  The result I'm getting is a single column of tuples, not the multiple columns that I want.  To wit:

```
sandbox=# CREATE FUNCTION myfunc(arg int) RETURNS table(col1 int, col2 int) AS
sandbox-# 'SELECT arg+1, arg+2'
sandbox-# LANGUAGE SQL;
CREATE FUNCTION
sandbox=# select * from myfunc(1);
 col1 | col2 
------+------
    2 |    3
(1 row)

sandbox=# WITH rows AS (
sandbox(#   SELECT 1 AS arg UNION SELECT 2 AS arg
sandbox(# )
sandbox-# SELECT * FROM (SELECT myfunc(arg) FROM rows) x;
 myfunc 
--------
 (2,3)
 (3,4)
(2 rows)
```

Given the CTE, the following two `SELECT` clauses evaluate identically to each other as a table with a single column of type `record`:

```
SELECT myfunc(arg) FROM rows;
SELECT * FROM (select myfunc(arg) FROM rows) x;
```

And the following three all fail (CTE not shown):

```
SELECT myfunc(arg).col1 FROM rows;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 4: SELECT myfunc(arg).col1 FROM rows;
                          ^

SELECT col1 FROM (select myfunc(arg) FROM rows) x;
ERROR:  column "col1" does not exist
LINE 4: SELECT col1 FROM (select myfunc(arg) FROM rows) x;
               ^

SELECT col1 FROM (SELECT * FROM (select myfunc(arg) FROM rows) x) y;
ERROR:  column "col1" does not exist
LINE 4: SELECT col1 FROM (SELECT * FROM (select myfunc(arg) FROM row...
               ^
```

How to I get a multi-column table containing the values that are in the single column of tuples?

Comment: You can try to use `LATERAL` if you have postgres 9.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's important to have extra parentheses around myfunc.

```
select (myfunc(arg)).* from rows;
```

Comment: Bingo.  I already marked it correct, but if I could I'd give extra points for pointing to the part of the Postgres manual one would read to have figured that out.  My hindsight is not 20/20.